# Speed Enhancements for a Sorted Vector in MATLAB

Tags: optimization, matlab

What is the fastest way to lookup the index of a value in sorted vector in MATLAB?
That is, is there a fast `find(vector == myNumber, 1, 'first')` for when vector is sorted?

I have a large matrix (200,000 x 4) of locations each with a unique integer ID recorded in the first column. I want to find the right the location of a known ID but thousands of searches can take me a little bit to find.

Comment: For a more general form including inequality, see this question: [Fast Searching in a sorted vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461972/fast-searching-for-the-lowest-value-greater-than-x-in-a-sorted-vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use ismembc2, the loc output should give you what you need.  See this for more details:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9NIE1N/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-9NIE1N

Comment: +1 very useful function. [Yair Altman](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function/) also blogged about it

Comment: Benchmarks for 100 random searches of a 2^24 Element vector: IsMember Time: 2.142869, Find Time: 1.586328, IsMembc2 Time: 0.000723

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of submissions for this on FEX:    http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=binary+search+vector

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is faster but you may want to try

```
result=vector(vector(:,1)==myNumber,:)
```

`result` will contain the 4 elements row for which vector `first column == myNumber`

Comment: Looped speed test indicates this is not faster in R2010a.