# Fast searching for the lowest value greater than x in a sorted vector

Tags: matlab, optimization

Fast means better than O(N), which is as good as find() is capable of. I know there is `ismembc` and `ismembc2`, but I don't think either of them are what I am looking for. I read the documentation and it seems they search for a member *equal* to x, but I want the index of *first value greater* than x.

Now if either of these functions *is* capable of doing this, could somebody please give an example, because I can't figure it out.

Ideal behaviour:

```
first_greater_than([0, 3, 3, 4, 7], 1)
```

returns 2, the index of the first value greater than 1, though obviously the input array would be vastly larger.

Of course, a binary search isn't too difficult to implement, but if MATLAB has already done it, I would rather use their method.

Comment: You you used `find`? You are aware of the `'first'` property? `find([0, 3, 3, 4, 7] > 1, 1,'first')` is exactly doing what you want.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I think your answer just returns the index, need to get the value further with the index. The method itself is elegant enough.

Comment: I does, but you can adress your initial vector with that vatiable: `A = [0, 3, 3, 4, 7]` and `A(find(A > 1, 1,'first')) = 3`

Comment: @thewaywewalk What did I *just say* about find() in the OP?

Comment: @Ray Whoops. I meant it returns the index. The index is far more useful. Editing the OP now.

Comment: I read this, but I obviously got your intention wrong.

Comment: Related: [Speed Enhancements for a Sorted Vector in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733581/speed-enhancements-for-a-sorted-vector-in-matlab)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin That's not a duplicate, since the question is not about finding an exact value, but a value greater than a threshold.

Comment: @EitanT Indeed, have withdrawn the close vote.

Comment: Yeah I read that one first too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the input is already sorted a custom binary search should work (you may need to do some updates for edge cases, *i.e* value requested is less than all elements of the array):

```
function [result, res2] = binarySearchExample(val) 

    %// Generate example data and sort it
    N = 100000000;
    a = rand(N, 1);
    a = sort(a);

    %// Run the algorithm
    tic % start timing of the binary search algorithm
    div = 1;
    idx = floor(N/div);
    while(1)
        div = div * 2;

        %// Check if less than val check if the next is greater
        if a(idx) <= val,
            if a(idx + 1) > val,
                result = a(idx + 1);
                break
            else %// Get bigger 
                idx = idx + max([floor(N / div), 1]);
            end
        end
        if a(idx) > val, % get smaller
            idx = idx - floor(N / div);
        end
    end % end the while loop
    toc % end timing of the binary search algorithm

    %% ------------------------
    %% compare to MATLAB find
    tic % start timing of a matlab find
    j = find(a > val, 1);
    res2 = a(j);
    toc % end timing of a matlab find

%// Benchmark
>> [res1, res2] = binarySearchExample(0.556)

Elapsed time is 0.000093 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.327183 seconds.

res1 =
   0.5560

res2 =
   0.5560
```

Comment: why did you put the comparison to `find` inside the `while` loop? why `tic-toc` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, I had considered this an option for sure, and it looks like it's what I'll end up doing since I am running out of time, but it wasn't what I was looking for. I was hoping there would be a MATLAB function for it. For now, I'll still have to leave your (albeit very nice) answer unaccepted, since it wasn't really what I was after. I will edit the question in response.

Comment: Where's the `tic` for the first time measurement?

Comment: @EitanT something feels fishy about the `tic-toc`s here... I would take these measurments with a grain of salt.

Comment: The tic-tocs are placed wrong, but the binary search is indeed faster than using a brute force O(n) lookup (even if implemented with a while loop). I've just tested it myself.

Comment: @EitanT Perhaps you can fix the (timing) code in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation. This is not quite the answer I was looking for, but for now, I will have to assume what I am after is not implemented in MATLAB.

### A Note on Indices

All MATLAB indices are done wrong, in that they start from 1 and not 0. I
still index from 0, though, in spite of this. So throughout, you will see
indexing that looks like this: `array(1+i)` accesses element i, where i is
in [0, N). Also, all MATLAB ranges are done wrong. Their convention is
[a, b], instead of [a, b). So you will see ranges that look like this
throughout: 0:N-1 is the range of numbers (often indices of an
N-dimensional array) from 0 to N. When arrays are indexed with a range,
both corrections have to be made at the same time. 1 is added to the top
and bottom boundary and 1 is subtracted from the top. This is the result:
array(1+a:b) accesses elements in [a, b), where a and b are in [0, N)
and b > a. I should really just be using python and scipy instead, but it's too late for that. Next project...

**binary_search.m:** It is much tidier than @ljk07's implementation in my opinion, but they still get an accept, of course. Thanks, @ljk07.

```
function i = binary_search(v, x)
%binary_search finds the first element in v greater than x
% v is a vector and x is a double. Returns the index of the desired element
% as an int64 or -1 if it doesn't exist.

% We'll call the first element of v greater than x v_f.

% Is v_f the zeroth element? This is technically covered by the algorithm,
% but is such a common case that it should be addressed immediately. It
% would otherwise take the same amount of time as the rest of them. This
% will add a check to each of the others, though, so it's a toss-up to an
% extent.
if v(1+0) > x
    i = 0;
    return;
end

% MATLAB foolishly returns the number of elements as a floating point
% constant. Thank you very much, MATLAB.
b = int64(numel(v));

% If v_f doesn't exist, return -1. This is also needed to ensure the
% algorithm later on terminates, which makes sense.
if v(1+b-1) <= x
    i = -1;
    return;
end

a = int64(0);

% There is now guaranteed to be more than one element, since if there
% wasn't, one of the above would have matched. So we split the [a, b) range
% at the top of the loop.

% The number of elements in the interval. Calculated once per loop. It is
% recalculated at the bottom of the loop, so it needs to be calculated just
% once before the loop can begin.
n = b;
while true
    % MATLAB's / operator foolishly rounds to nearest instead of flooring
    % when both inputs are integers. Thank you very much, MATLAB.
    p = a + idivide(n, int64(2));

    % Is v_f in [a, p) or [p, b)?
    if v(1+p-1) > x
        % v_f is in [a, p).
        b = p;
    else
        % v_f is in [p, b).
        a = p;
    end

    n = b - a;
    if n == 1
        i = a;
        return;
    end
end
end
```

**binary_search_test.m:**

```
% Some simple tests. These had better pass...
assert(binary_search([0], 0) == -1);
assert(binary_search([0], -1) == 0);

assert(binary_search([0 1], 0.5) == 1);
assert(binary_search([0 1 1], 0.5) == 1);
assert(binary_search([0 1 2], 0.5) == 1);
assert(binary_search([0 1 2], 1.5) == 2);

% Compare the algorithm to internal find.
for n = [1 1:8]
    n
    v = sort(rand(10^n, 1));
    x = 0.5;
    %%
    tic;
    ifind = find(v > x, 1,'first') - 1;
    toc;
    % repeat. The second time is faster usually. Some kind of JIT
    % optimisation...
    tic;
    ifind = find(v > x, 1,'first') - 1;
    toc;
    tic;
    ibs = binary_search(v, x);
    toc;
    tic;
    ibs = binary_search(v, x);
    toc;
    assert(ifind == ibs);
end
```

**Output** of binary_search_test.m (on my computer):

```
n =

     1

Elapsed time is 0.000054 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000021 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001273 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001135 seconds.

n =

     2

Elapsed time is 0.000050 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000018 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001571 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001494 seconds.

n =

     3

Elapsed time is 0.000034 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000025 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002344 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002193 seconds.

n =

     4

Elapsed time is 0.000057 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000044 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003131 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003031 seconds.

n =

     5

Elapsed time is 0.000473 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000333 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003620 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003161 seconds.

n =

     6

Elapsed time is 0.003984 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003635 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004209 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003825 seconds.

n =

     7

Elapsed time is 0.034811 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.039106 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.005089 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004867 seconds.

n =

     8

Elapsed time is 0.322853 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.323777 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.005969 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.005487 seconds.
```

There is definitely a speedup. On my computer you can see the speedup is reached in around the one million element mark. So unless binary_search is implemented in C or you have a vector with about million elements, find is *still* faster, even though it is using a stupid algorithm. I was expecting the threshold to be waaay lower than that. My guess is because find is mostly internally implemented in C. Not fair :( But nevertheless, for my particular application, I have vector sizes of only about a thousand, so after all that, find really is faster for me. At least until the day I implement binary_search in C with a mex file or switch to scipy, whichever happens first. I'm kind of getting tired of MATLAB's little inconvenient switchups. You can tell by reading the comments in my code.